# How to get boolean or of two numpy masks with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two numpy array masks, created with the 3rd and 4th columns of data of 7 columns total:

```
exp_mask = np.repeat(data[:,2]>7., data.shape[1])
loggf_mask = np.repeat(data[:,3]<-7., data.shape[1])
```

How can I mask data which are masked by either `exp_mask` or `loggf_mask`?

The logic of what I am trying to describe is:

```
mask = exp_mask or loggf_mask
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for a bitwise or, which is |.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.any() to evaluate boolean or on masks:

```
mask = np.any([exp_mask,loggf_mask],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`bitwise_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html#numpy.bitwise_or), which also has the `|` shorthand, or [`logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or).  Both will work since your array will be of type `bool`:

```
mask = exp_mask | loggf_mask
```